# Scipy Optimize - how to set stock weight lower boundary

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, portfolio

I'm trying to a create minimum variance portfolio with no short sales allowed. I'm getting the correct solutions however I would like to set stock weights between 5% and 15%. I've added the upper boundary and it works fine, however don't know the right way to add the lower boundary.

```
def objective(w):
return np.matmul(short,np.matmul(covvar,shortweights))
w = np.random.random(497)
e = ones
const = ({'type' : 'eq' , 'fun' : lambda w: np.dot(w,e) - 1})  # sum(w) - 1 = 0
non_neg = []
for i in range(497):
  non_neg.append((0,.15))
non_neg = tuple(non_neg)
solution = minimize(fun=objective, x0=w, method='SLSQP',constraints=const,bounds=non_neg)
w = solution.x.round(6)
```

Comment: Isn't it just `(0.05, .15)` instead of `(0,.15)`?

Comment: In case you mean 0 or between 0.05 and 0.15: this results in a MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Program). This is not supported by scipy.optimize. Note that advanced solvers have a special type for this: semi-continuous decision variables.

Comment: @chappers No, in that case, the lowest total weight of the portfolio is 0.05*497, as no stock will go below 0.05, it should be 0 or between 0.05 & 0.15.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks! Can you recommend any library that has an advanced solver?

Comment: Cplex and Gurobi come to mind (commercial, free for academics). I am not sure about free solvers for commercial use. CvxPy is useful for modeling.